# "NumPy-est" way to generate equilateral grid

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, numpy-ndarray

I have a rectangular extent [[left, bottom], [right, top]] and an initial point [x, y]. I want to fill the extent with the equilateral point grid (of width w) on which the initial point lies.

So far I've found the top-left point via

```
h = w * math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0
start = np.array([right - ((right - x) % w), top - ((top - y) % h)])
```

And I can generate the x & y positions with

```
x_in_row = np.arange(start[0], right, w)
x_in_off_row = x_in_row - w / 2.0
row_y = np.arange(start[1], bottom, -h)
```

Now I want to combine those to generate an n x 2 array (of n points). I'm quite new to NumPy and I know there are lots of ways to elegantly combine arrays I just have trouble thinking about the dimensions and the correct functions to use for each purpose. Is there a nice sequence/combination of functions to achieve this?

Comment: Look into [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: As I understood, the step in *x* axis is *w* and the step in *y* axis is *h*.
Since *w* and *h* are different, the grid you want to create is **not** equilateral.
It would be equilateral if the step in both axes was just the same.

Comment: Oops I meant equilateral triangle grid

Answer (score 0):

```py
x_values = np.arange(start[0],right,w)
y_values = np.arange(start[1],bottom,-h)
points = np.c_[tuple(np.ravel(mesh) for mesh in np.meshgrid(x_values,y_values))]
```

Example with dummy data

```py
>>> x_values = [1,2,3]
>>> y_values = [4,5,6]
>>> np.c_[tuple(np.ravel(mesh) for mesh in np.meshgrid(x_values,y_values))]
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate the range of values for each dimension, define the following function:

```
def getRng(rngStart, rngStop, step, start):
    wrk = np.arange(rngStart, rngStop, step) - start
    shft = wrk[wrk < 0][-1]
    return np.arange(rngStart - shft, rngStop, step)
```

To test it I assumed the following data:

```
left, bottom = 0, 0
right, top   = 3, 2
x, y = 0.4, 0.12      # Starting point
w = 0.25; h = 0.3     # Step in x / y axis
```

Then I generated ranges for both axes:

```
rngX = getRng(left, right, w, x)
rngY = getRng(bottom, top, h, y)
```

getting:

```
array([0.15, 0.4 , 0.65, 0.9 , 1.15, 1.4 , 1.65, 1.9 , 2.15, 2.4 , 2.65, 2.9 ])
array([0.12, 0.42, 0.72, 1.02, 1.32, 1.62, 1.92])
```

And to generate the expected result (a list of points), you can run:

```
result = np.transpose([np.tile(rngX, rngY.size), np.repeat(rngY, rngX.size)])
```

The initial part of it is:

```
array([[0.15, 0.12],
       [0.4 , 0.12],
       [0.65, 0.12],
       [0.9 , 0.12],
       [1.15, 0.12],
       [1.4 , 0.12],
       [1.65, 0.12],
       [1.9 , 0.12],
       [2.15, 0.12],
       [2.4 , 0.12],
       [2.65, 0.12],
       [2.9 , 0.12],
```

and then follow similiar "sections" for other values from *rngY*.

## Edit

Another, more concise solution to generate the final result is:

```
result2 = np.array(np.meshgrid(rngX, rngY)).T.reshape(-1,2)
```

(the order of points is different, but in my opinion it is not important).